# Windows Azure vs Amazon EC2

Tags: .net, web-services, azure, amazon-ec2

I want to do something pretty simple, but I'm not sure what the best solution is. Basically, I want to host a custom .NET web service for a client. The web service is just an integration as it  will select data from one source, massage the data, and insert it into its destination. My two-part question is the following:

1. Windows Azure and Amazon EC2 can handle this, correct?
2. If yes, are these solutions over-kill? We'd like to get our feet wet with the cloud and plan on using either of these platforms in the future, but it seems to me that simply hosting a web service for a client doesn't require a robust/scalable hosting solution (unless it's cost effective.)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two competing parts here:

> are these solutions over-kill?

and

> We'd like to get our feet wet with the cloud

For the first part, the answer is "it depends".  But very possibly they are.  But the second part means it doesn't matter.  A "simple" service like this is an ideal way to test and get a feel for the systems before going all in with them. You could even build the service in both systems as a way to decide which one you like working with better.

Comment: You're right as we do have long term goals for using these types of services, so maybe starting small is an ideal way to get acclimated. With that said, either of these platforms can handle what we want to do, correct? (host a custom .NET web service)

Comment: Yes. For a .Net service I'd probably start with Azure.  But I think EC2 can do this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Don't even touch Windows Azure to do this, you'll pay 2x or more the cost.  Boot up an EC2 instance running Windows (or if you really want to save and have a more performant web service, startup a SUSE Linux Instance and use mono).

Windows Azure will cost you more to do less for something so simple.  Unless you need SQL Azure or AppFabric, there is almost no reasons to use Windows Azure.  I've written up some blog entries based on price comparisons, boot up times, and other key characteristics.

http://compositecode.com/2010/11/01/cloudthrowdown-part1/
and
http://compositecode.com/2010/11/03/cloudthrowdown-part2/

The other advantage of AWS is you'll actually become more familiar with the infrastructure aspects of what you're trying to do.  Windows Azure hides that from you, which can be good sometimes, but if you're trying to learn about cloud computing you should step into the AWS offerings.

Comment: AWS is IaaS, Azure is PaaS. I don't personally have experience with AWS, but PaaS takes a lot of the headache out of maintaining a production environment and you can focus on the code. Azure is also a first class citizen in VS making deployments a breeze and giving a lot of debugging capabilities (though the deployment process is currently slow, exceptions are unhelpful - but it is still early days). Plus you get SQL Azure, which is almost as good as onpremise.

Comment: Moving forwards to 2014 after Azure has been under Scott Gu's care for a while now, you'll find Azure both more cost effective and giving a much better developer experience.  You host a web service in an Azure Website which costs peanuts and you can deploy and debug directly into the running code. Azure does give a truly awesome cloud development experience IMO!

Comment: Please note this answer was provided in November of '10. When Azure had zero competitive featureset compared to AWS. Today it is different, but it's important to note the time in which I provided the answer and the throwdowns the offering of Azure was entirely different.